# How transfer 404 page to search

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, magento

I am new to this magento world and don't have any developing skills. I have magento store for which we are changing the server and all the data inside that.

Fore each product, the url will be changed and it will generate a lot of 404 result which are not good for SEO.

Is there any way we can turn those 404 pages to relative search?
there is one extension: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=404+to+search&pl=0

but that does not work with our magento 1.9.0.1 we have tried to contact developer but he doesn't seem to be interesting in replying.

any easy way guys I can just edit some code in my 404 page and it will start showing the search result? or any other extension you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no need for an extension to do that. 
Under *Catalog* > *URL Rewrite Management*, in your admin, you can rewrite URLs for a category, for a product, or for a custom URL.
You can then have your old outdated url Permanent (301) redirect to the new URLs in your Magento.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to develop a custom extension to capture the 404 event and then redirect the url to the search. However, if development is not an option you probably better try an already done extension. If you have a list of affected urls, you can try this extension which supports Magento 1.9: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/optimise-web-s-mass-301-redirects-for-404-pages.html but note that you will need to provide a CSV with all the 404 pages and the corresponding redirection for each case.